# How can I get straight lines on a UV map?

Tags: uv, edges

How can I set straight several edges in one action?

My current workflow is to select each edge, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do it, as with the **Loop Tools -> Relax** button.

I know the UV squares has the feature to grid by shape, but what I need is to get several edges on the same axis straight without affect the angle of the edges on the other axis.

Is that possible?
Can you help?

[image: Screenshot of edge selection#1]

[image: Screenshot of edge selection#2]

Comment: It's a complete different thing. I want to edit manually each uv map, I don't want to straight the entire map- I want an answer who helps me to speed my workflow

Comment: The entire thing pictured in the question is the UV map.

Comment: the uv squares straights the entire grid, I want to get straight the edges along one single axis.

Comment: Is the second image what you want?  If so, [S]-[X]-`0` or [space}-`align`-[enter] will work.

Comment: @pgmath is that what I want but for all the edges along the x axis, without affecting the edges along y axis. in one single action.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from perhaps some add-on, I'm not sure of a way to do what you want in *one action*. If you are open to another solution, perhaps consider the *align auto* function in the UV specials menu. It does basically the same thing as scaling to 0 on X or Y, but can save time as you can just use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the operator after using it.

Just <kbd>Alt</kbd>select your edge, and then use <kbd>W</kbd>><kbd>A</kbd>*(Align Auto)* to activate the operator, followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> after each selection to repeat the function.

[image]